# SQL query works in DB client but not works within the Laravel app

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, sequelpro

I have a custom SQL query that is loading perfectly fine within my Sequel Pro database application, however when this is loaded through my Laravel app I am getting an error on my web app.

The error i'm getting it as follows : Syntax error or access violation: 1055 't.player' isn't in GROUP BY

The query is below in the gist
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/56734604007a2698277809a528c50095

Comment: Your query loading fine in Sequel Pro but your query is not correct https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/...

Comment: Figured it out... Laravel has a bizarre 'strict' setting for mysql, it fails when set to true but works when true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned the MySQL strict setting to 'OFF' and this is working ok now.